# What are the right settings for Ubuntu Touch under qemu?

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, emulation

As you can see [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/), Canonical is releasing the images for Ubuntu touch, the problem is that apparently those are snapshots from a complete installation, there is no installer here and no vmlinuz + initrd.

Also in `qemu-system-arm -M help` there is no platform that can fit one of the 4 that are officially supported, Does anyone knows how to run Ubuntu touch under qemu ? I have tried the classic way with kernel options and different boot options but nothing happens, I also can't really figure out what Canonical means with `bootimg`, they are supposed to be initrd ? kernel images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot.img are images for fastboot that contain the kernel. It's android specific.
You can unpack these, but there is no build for a reference board that Qemu supports.

You can run Unity-next on the desktop. This is build in Qt and QML so as long as all dependies are build on the desktop, it can run. Here's a how-to:
http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unitynext/